# Decode Json Object Php

Tags: php, android, json, decode

My json data looks like this :

```
{
 "amount":550,
 "items":[
    {"item_id":12334, "price": 504}, 
    {"item_id":12335, "price":206}
  ]
}
```

I want to know how to parse this data in order to fetch each information in separate variable.

Comment: parse with what? Php or certain android json library.

Comment: Do you want to parse in android or in PHP on server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you can use `json_decode($myJsonString)`, while in Android you might look for a third party library, [GSON](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-introduction.jsp) is a good one though

```
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach($data->items as $item) {
   echo $item->item_id . ' ' . $item->price;
}
```

Comment: yes, I know this function. After decoding I got something like this:
stdClass Object ( [amount] => 550 [items] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [item_id] => 12334 [price] => 504 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [item_id] => 12335 [price] => 206 ) ) )

I have succefully fetched amount but stuck at fetching item_id/price inside the items.

Comment: Thanks @Iwan, I was doing the same but was not parsing item_id and price as object. I have fixed my code.

Answer (score 0):

- In PHP use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
- In Java use [org.json.simple](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm)

Comment: yes, I know this function. After decoding I got something like this:
stdClass Object ( [amount] => 550 [items] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [item_id] => 12334 [price] => 504 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [item_id] => 12335 [price] => 206 ) ) )

I have succefully fetched amount but stuck at fetching item_id/price inside the items.

Answer (score 0):

Create local variable suppose $response;

store your output in $response;

You can fetch price by following code.

foreach ($response->items as $item){

```
 echo $item->price;
 echo "<br>";
```

}